# iOS - Silent push notification to send value

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

Is there a way to send values from a php page to objective-c? I want to simulate the event programming with the push notification: when in the web server change a value, it sends the value to the iOS in silent mode with the push notifications.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-ios-push-notification-services-for-beginners/